# How do I confirm the SKU for an in-app Google Extension purchase?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've read and reread the one-time purchase and in-app purchase examples and am i missing the step to convert the response from a call to the Google Web Store API.

I've got payment working (in test mode).But can't figure out how to check to see if the user has actually paid. I don't understand how to unpack whatever it is that Google gives back.

I've only got one SKU, so don't need to display a list (like the example assumes).

Here's a lightly modified (from the example provided by Google) code snippet where I'm trying to get the SKU of items purchased by a user. I'm just trying to pop up the value in an alert to reverse engineer the right syntax. I am writing the values to the console just fine.But all I get in my alert is "undefined."

```
    function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
    console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
    var licenses = response.response.details;
    var count = licenses.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var license = licenses[i];
    alert(license.sku);
    //    addLicenseDataToProduct(license);
    }
    //  statusDiv.text("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, combo of JSON research and trial and error got me to a solution.

Note to other hackers (and Google): Extensions are a great entry point for people who want to build things but don't have any formal training. I had a vague notion of JSON but no experience with it...the instructions and example for Google Web Store leave out crucial steps if you don't know how to deal with the return from a simple API.

I've only got one SKU so far, so I needed to check, specifically, for the first in the array - which is zero, not one.

```
var license = licenses[0];
alert(license.sku)
```

The above code properly pops up the sku the user has already purchased. So now I can use this call to enforce payment elsewhere in my app.

Here's my purchase.js code - lightly modified from the example Google provides.

```
function CheckPurchases(){              //What license do we already have?
  console.log("google.payments.inapp.getPurchases");
//  statusDiv.text("Retreiving list of purchased products...");
  google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
    'parameters': {env: "prod"},
    'success': onLicenseUpdate,
    'failure': onLicenseUpdateFailed
  });

}

function onPurchase(){
            alert('Made a purchase');
}

function onPurchaseFail(){
            alert('Failed to make a purchase');
}

function onLicenseUpdate(response) {
  console.log("onLicenseUpdate", response);
  var licenses = response.response.details;

    var license = licenses[0];
alert(license.sku)

  }
```